# How do i create powershell shortcut that closes automatically

Tags: powershell

I'm using a shortcut with a powershell command line for shutting down the monitor.
It does what it has to do except automatically close the powershell window after the rule is executed.

How do I change the command line so that the window closes automatically?

This is the command line I'm using:

```
    powershell.exe -Command "(Add-Type '[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd,int hMsg,int wParam,int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)"
```

Comment: add `; exit` just before the last quote ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Solution 1:** Add **'; exit'** after the first command, telling PowerShell there is an additional command.

```
powershell.exe -Command "(Add-Type '[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd,int hMsg,int wParam,int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)"; exit
```

**Solution 2:** If the first example does not work you can tell cmd to pass your command into a PowerShell process, if the shortcut is not acting properly.

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c powershell.exe -Command "(Add-Type '[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd,int hMsg,int wParam,int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)" & exit
```

Comment: Note that a `powershell -Command` call normally exits _automatically_ after executing the given command (unless you also specify `-NoExit`), so the OP's symptom suggests that the command never finishes; if that is the case, an explicit `exit` won't help, and calling via `cmd /c` shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: The first solution (adding exit) works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: - No problem Aventurjin! 
- mklement, when creating a shortcut for a command the context is different. “Powershell -command ‘do x,y, z’ ” is treated as two steps: 1. Open powershell session (the same as a user created session) 2. Execute a commands in the session terminal. The other cmd example works because similarly it is treated as a “user created session”. 1.cmd opens and runs the powershell process and its command in a separate process that is not treated as a “user created session” which then automatically closes, finally the exit command is sent to the cmd closing the initial window.

Comment: Mklement the command will finish, and I stop its execution if it fails so the process will not get hung up, meaning the exit statement works. The example of using cmd to send a command to a powershell process functions as you mentioned, but the initial cmd window needs to be closed, hence & exit. Please test this on your local machine by creating a shortcut with my examples to see how it works

Comment: No: A `powershell -c` command normally exits automatically when the specified command finishes, irrespective of where it is called from. Try `powershell -c pause` as the command of a shortcut file, and you'll see that the window closes automatically as soon as you press a key. The same goes for `cmd /c`. To create sessions that do _not_ auto-close, you need `powershell -noexit ...` or `cmd /k`

Comment: In other words: good know that the explicit `exit` solved the OP's problem, but _we don't know why it is needed_ in this particular case, and it is important to note that is normally _not_ needed. Also, the `cmd /c` variation adds nothing to the solution.